# Is it possible to use Entity Framework without LINQ?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is it possible to use Entity Framework without LINQ (linq to entities)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by using Linq to Entities and EF separately. That's a single library *EntityFramework.dll*. If you want to write queries on plain SQL, you can do it with [SqlQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method of `DbSet` class:

```
var users = context.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Users").ToList();
```

In this case EF acts only as mapper, but it does not generates query.

**UPDATE** According to your comments, you want to avoid referencing Linq. And the answer is - you can't do that, because EF references *System.Linq* namespace. Consider to use NHibernate with Criteria API.

And remember - Linq is integrated into language. Better spend some time getting around it, than avoid it. Linq is very powerful and you will use it not only for database access, but for everyday working with in-memory collections, xml, datasets and so on.

Comment: +1 as close as you can get, even if it's not exactly the convenient way.

Comment: I would like to remove all referencies to linq. consider i don't like linq

Comment: @B413 You can use `context.Database.SqlQuery`, even if not convenient, that's pretty much the lowest level you can go, and does not use Linq. One example available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @B413 it is not possible, because EF relies on `IQueryable` which is defined in `System.Linq` namespace. Consider to use NHibernate with Criteria API, or Dapper.

Comment: The think is when I'm looking for a product like EF or NHibernate It's because I don't want to have to write SQL or LINQ queries. Also LinQ is limited. You cannot write dynamic linq queries or complex join queries.

Comment: @B413 dynamic queries? Typically those are used for filtering operations, which you can do dynamically. And joins in LINQ? You can certainly do joins, even those you may not expect (http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Left-Outer-Joins-in-LINQ-with-Entity-Framework)  but for complex items, what's the concern? An ORM is meant to map your db types to code types. A complex join then ideally would just be a proc I'd add or execute in that few and far between case the SqlQuery() as others have mentioned. Either way, you have options. Removing LINQ should be the least concern.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it possible, but not sure why you would. If you are going to go the route of using queries like this:

```
var users = context.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Users").ToList();
```

as suggested above, then why not ditch EF altogether and use something like [dapper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/&ei=iUW3UaiLJc6q0AHN2YDACA&usg=AFQjCNHDo-0KnatIhtMQ4pvQ0QLhup59Wg&sig2=WPuM89b8DVEDhlogakg_7g&bvm=bv.47534661,d.dmQ), which is incredibly easy to use and very fast with a less overhead. Using EF without the linq gives you all the bad parts of of EF (the bloat, slow speeds), without the benefits of the LINQ querying capabilities which makes it so powerful.