# Is it mandatory to use Linq when using entity framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using entity framework for my project. I just started reading about entity framework. Is it necessary to use LINQ? When I am looking at this website, it does not use LINQ anywhere. So, are there two ways of using EF- with and without LINQ?

link to the tutorial
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/Introduction.aspx

Comment: That site *does* use LINQ in all the examples I saw. Would you like to be more specific about what you think LINQ is and examples that don't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from "What is Entity Framework" in the link you provided:

> The Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework is an Object/Relational Mapping
>   (ORM) framework that enables developers to work with relational data
>   as domain-specific objects, eliminating the need for most of the data
>   access plumbing code that developers usually need to write. **Using the
>   Entity Framework, developers issue queries using LINQ, then retrieve
>   and manipulate data as strongly typed objects.** The Entity Framework’s
>   ORM implementation provides services like change tracking, identity
>   resolution, lazy loading, and query translation so that developers can
>   focus on their application-specific business logic rather than the
>   data access fundamentals.

Comment: @Jonathan Diana Sorry guys. I got confused with lambda expressions. I didn't realize linq queries could be written using lambda expressions as well. Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

Its not mandatory to use LINQ while using entity framework.
But it would make things easier if you know the syntax of LINQ and take advantage of functionality it gives.

[Is it possible to use Entity Framework without LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047817/is-it-possible-to-use-entity-framework-without-linq)
http://forums.asp.net/t/1948335.aspx?Can+I+Learn+or+Use+Entity+Framework+Without+Knowing+LINQ+To+SQL+